# Python reads csv in just one column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So im am relativley new to python (using Python 3 with the spyder IDE) and i try to read in a csv file with some weather data.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7z9N.png)
The problem is that the file i have contains some empty cells and information i dont need. I only need from the row 18 as a header (all the physical descriptions of the data e.g. Temperature, pressure etc are stored in this row) and all columns. When i try the following in python:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\troes\OneDrive\Dokumente\studium\8 Semester\BAT\code_transfer\VNYA16.201812160000.csv')

df = df[16:91]
```

Python stores all of the data in just one column like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7z9N.png)

But the output i want is a dataframe which contains in the first column the DATE_TIME, second LEAD_TIME, third T_2M_K and so on.

Does anybody know how to fix that properly?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are those commas in your file? They look like semicolons to me. Write `sep=";"` csv stands for comma separated values.

Comment: `read_csv` has a `sep` parameter, for starters. It also has `skiprows`.

Comment: using sep=(';') gives me the following error: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 4, saw 5, the problem is i think the 2 empty cells at the start in row 18

Comment: Did you try using `skiprows` or `header`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you move in the right direction:

`pd.read_csv()` can take some extra arguments. See Pandas Doc here: [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Firstly, since you have extra rows before the header, add the header argument to specify the row. e.g

```py
pd.read_csv(path_to_file, header = 17)
```

The default seperator in `read_csv()` is ',' whereas it looks like your seperator is ';'. I would therefore also add the seperator argument. e.g:

```py
pd.read_csv(path_to_file, header=17, sep=';')
```

Hopefully, that gets you something more reasonable.

Comment: Thank you very much. that gave me exactly the output i wanted

Comment: No problem. If you can, please mark the answer as accepted for anyone looking this up in future and happy pythoning.

Answer (score 0):

In pandas, the default sepearator is a comma (not much of a suprise since csv stands for 'comma seperated values'). Yours is a semicolon. To change it, you need to modify your command to include something like: `pd.read_csv(sep=';')`. If that's not quite enough, the full line would be:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\troes\OneDrive\Dokumente\studium\8 Semester\BAT\code_transfer\VNYA16.201812160000.csv', sep=';')
```

Here's a [link to the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) in case want to know more.

Comment: thank for your help, but is the exact same line i have in my file. i already tried sep=(";") and that gives me the following error from python: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 4, saw 5

Comment: Try that again with copying what I put in. I say that because both in your comment above as well as the one on your question you're saying you've typed in " sep=(';')  " which isn't what is being suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Use `skip_rows` functionality of `pd.read_csv`.

```
df = (pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\troes\OneDrive\Dokumente\studium\8 Semester\BAT\code_transfer\VNYA16.201812160000.csv', 
                  sep=';', 
                  skip_rows=18))
```